# Iaijutsu dueling rules

Tags: l5r-4e

I find iaijutsu dueling weird in 4th.
This is what I understand so far:

If someone doesn't roll high enough to strike first, the duel is over and considered a draw.

That seems a weird rule.
I feel like there is something I'm missing here.

Could someone explain please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Iaijutsu duels occur in 3 stages:

1. **Assessment**: The two duelists study each other, analyzing their techniques, and attempt to determine who is the superior duelist. Mechanically, beating this roll gives you a bonus as you are able to pick out the weaknesses in your opponent's technique
2. **Focus**: The two duelist settle into a meditative state, feeling for the perfect moment to strike. Mechanically, this determines who finds that perfect moment first, and thus strikes first.
3. **Strike**: The duelists draw their blades, attacking each other as quickly as possible. If you hit, and the duel is to first blood, then you win. Otherwise, the other guy strikes, and the duel devolves into a skirmish.

Your problem, is the fact that, if nobody wins the focus roll by at least 5, both duelists strike at the same time in a karmic strike. Why does this end the duel?

Since a duel is usually intended to determine who the Fortunes declare to be correct in a dispute, a strike at the same time indicates that both sides of the dispute are correct. The dispute is settled, assuming that both duelists hit with their strike rolls.

Please note that the duel is only over in a duel to first blood. If the duel is to the death, then everyone continues trying to kill each other until one of them is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading the book right now and i have a different interpretation on the rules.

> In the event that neither opponent won the Contested Roll durin rhe
>   focus stage, **both make their attack rolls simultaneously**, an event
>   known as **kharmic strike**.

Emphasis mine.

Assuming the duel is first blood.

1) Both succeed on the attack roll, then it's a draw.

2) One succeed and the other fail, the one that hits won.

3) Both fail the attack roll, the duel becomes a standard skirmish until someone is hit.